# Why Prashar Samithi 3:36 says that who ever is killed in the battlefield will get Devkanyas? And who exactly are Devkanyas?

Tags: translation-request

I saw many translations and Prashar Samithi 3 36 says When a hero dies, Devkanyas take him. Who exactly are Devkanyas and what is the actual translation of this?

Answer (score 2):

> **Celestial damsels** seize for themselves, and take delight with the hero, whose body is wounded or cut by arrows, clubs, or maces.
>
> Thousands of **celestial damsels,** rush forward in a hurry towards a
> hero killed in battle, each proclaiming, * He is my lord, he is mine.'
>
> The regions which Brahman aspirants after heavenly bliss reach by
> performing many sacrificial rites, and by austerities of various
> forms, — the same seats of bliss are attained in an instant's time by
> valorous men, who meet their death while blamelessly fighting on a
> field of battle. **(verses from Chapter 3)**

The relevant Sanskrit verses have the words *Devakanya* and *Devangana* in them, which are translated above as "celestial damsels". According to Hindu scriptures, anyone who gives his life while fighting in a battleground goes straight to heavens. Devakanyas (damsels residing in the celestial planes of heaven) receive them and want such heroes to be their lords (husbands). That is only what is meant.

[image]